# Trying to setup a Neural Network, having some trouble with structure

Tags: java, neural-network

I am trying to setup a very simple neural network, which will use a multilayered perceptron approach.

I have 4 classes:

> **Node**: which only has a constructor with nothing in it, and an output method (which I still have to define)
>
> **InputNode**: will read data from a .data file and setup input nodes (in double types) according to data
>
> **HiddenLayer**: This layer will be 2/3 the size of the length of each Input ArrayList
>
> **NeuralNetwork**: This will be the main execution class, where I will setup a 2-d double array with randomized weights. Those weights will be multiplied by the input data to get a sum. There will be an error and a train method present here.

My question pertains to the InputNode and the HiddenLayer class. I want the InputNode class to read data from a .data file and setup each row from the .data into 13 input nodes. The last number of each row in the .data file represents a predictive number of 0-3: negative for something or above 3: positive for something

*Example:*

If I have 13 inputs, then I should have around 8 hidden nodes. Each hidden node will take in all the input nodes and multiply the input value of each input node times the weight of that specific hidden node and come up with either a 1 or -1 value.

How would I go about setting this up? Having some trouble with this since I had originally setup my NeuralNetwork class to setup an input ArrayList, but now have decided that it is better to create separate classes.

Here is what an example dataset would look like:

[image: Data]

Here is the code for my Node Class:

```
public class Node {

public Node(){
    
}

public void output(){
    //Don't know what to put here? Guess it can be modified for hiddenlayer and
        // Node classes 
}

}
```

Here is the code for my InputNode Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputNode extends Node {

//declare arraylist for input nodes
private List<Node> inputs = new ArrayList<Node>();

//Constuctor for input nodes
public InputNode(File f){
    
    List<Node> tempInput = new ArrayList<Node>();
    this.inputs = tempInput;
    
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(f);
        
        //While there is another line in inFile.
        while (inFile.hasNextLine()){
            //Store that line into String line
            String line = inFile.nextLine();
            //Parition values separated by a comma
            String[] columns = line.split(",");
            /*System.out.println(columns.length); //Test code to see length of each column
            * code works and prints 14
            * */
            //create a double array of size columns
            double[] rows = new double[columns.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
                //For each row...
                if (!columns[i].equals("?")){
                    //If the values in each row do not equal "?"
                    //Set rows[i] to the values in column[i]
                    rows[i] = Double.parseDouble(columns[i]);
                }
                else {
                    rows[i] = 0;
                }
            }
            inputs.add(rows);
            }
        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}




}
```

Comment: Hi, it looks very interesting:D Since I do not know nothing abut neural science(And English is also no good), Can you explain little more specific what kind of data do you want to get? Anyway 'input.add(rows)' is a syntax error, because input is arraylist of Node Object and rows is an array of bytes.

Comment: Hi Juneyong thank you for being interested!

Answer (score 2):

I thought point of this question is how to identify '?' marks from mixed String array. I am not sure this is what you want but I suggest one possibility.

Follow is code to exchange '?' marks to double '0.0'.

I have changed some codes of yours.
- change ArrayList Generic from 'Node' to 'double[]', since it can not assign double array(which means 'rows' in your code) to Object ArrayList.
- add a try/catch phrase, because it can not cast literal signs to Integer or Double. so first we need to sort out this string is literal or numeral.

```
public class InputNode {

    private final String REGEX = ",";
    private final String Q_MARKS = "?";
    private List<double[]> input;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public InputNode(File f){
        this.input = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        try{
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(f);
            int cntLines = 0;

            while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
                String line = inFile.nextLine();
                String columns[] = line.split(REGEX);

                double rows[] = new double[columns.length];

                for(int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
                    //if String is '?' then 0.0, else parseDouble
                    if(!columns[i].equals(Q_MARKS)){
                        try{
                            rows[i] = Double.parseDouble(columns[i]);
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            System.out.println("data is not '?'");
                            continue;
                        }
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("data is '?' mark");
                        rows[i] = 0;
                    }
                }

                input.add(rows);
                cntLines++;
                System.out.println("num : " + cntLines + ", value : " + Arrays.toString(rows));
            }
            System.out.println("total Lines read : " + cntLines);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

My test a.data file is

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,3,0
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,?,12,6,0
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,?,?,?,0
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,?,?,?,0
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,?,?,?,0
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,?,?,?,1
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,18,19,10,?,?,?,0
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,?,?,3,0
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,?,?,?,1
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,?,?,?,0
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,?,?,2,0
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,?,?,?,0
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,?,?,?,0
```

And finally output was :

```
Riddles +_+
num : 1, value : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 3.0, 0.0]
data is '?' mark
num : 2, value : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 0.0, 12.0, 6.0, 0.0]
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
num : 3, value : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
num : 4, value : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
num : 5, value : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
num : 6, value : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
num : 7, value : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 18.0, 19.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
num : 8, value : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0]
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
num : 9, value : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
num : 10, value : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
num : 11, value : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0]
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
num : 12, value : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
data is '?' mark
num : 13, value : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
total Lines read : 13
```

Exchange all '?' marks to '0.0', you can math with that:D

Comment: This is not what I was trying to do, but thank you for helping! I am trying to figure out which classes will have what methods and how to put it together.

Comment: Maybe if there are many kind of Node like InputNode, OutputNode etc, it would be nice to make Node class to Interface. And it only has common members/methods. I thinks this method will be nicer if it is in 'NeuralNetwork' class, since others look like representing a data. Anyway, It is just my personal opinion.

Comment: You're absolutely right Juneyoung I had actually put this method in NeuralNetwork class again. I haven't done much work with interfaces, can you explain?

Comment: Sorry, but I thought wrong. it should be a class, not interface. However, if want to know about Interface you can read follow link. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: I usually use Interface when I define service which means logics, not data. Interface is something like class, but has no specific method. So if someone implements that, they can making code whatever they like. However, in name of interface has some intension of coder's purpose, make easier to co-operating. Sorry for make you confusing.

Comment: Since My English is shady enough, it put some link. http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/18/exploring-interfaces-and-abstract-classes-in-java/    this explains what is interface and its roll.